# dynamic progress bar is not display correctly when execute wget by nodejs spawn

Tags: node.js, terminal, wget, child-process, spawn

i write a node.js code just like below sample.

i use child_process.spawn to create child process for execute command 'wget'. at the same time i redirec standard i/o of child process to standard i/o of node.js process

```js
let cp = spawn('wget', 'some_file_url')
cp.stdin.pipe(process.stdin)
cp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
cp.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
```

now i execute code above in node.js, everything is ok but progress bar. it just looks like this:

```
     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  134K 5m21s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  631K 3m14s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 4.64M 2m12s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  167M 99s
```

normally, if i execute wget command on terminal

```sh
$ wget some_file_url
```

a dynamic progress bar will display in output

```
file.tar.gz                  15%[======>                                         ]   6.69M  2.27MB/s
```

so, how should i do to make the progress bar display like above

#### environments

- node.js: v14.16.1
- wget: GNU Wget 1.21.2 built on darwin21.1.0

#### sorry

my english is poor. please excuse grammar or typing error. i'm trying my best to imporve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect effect you did get is due to GNU Wget thinking its' `stderr` was redirected to file. I do not know how to get desired effect using GNU Wget, but if you need to just download file (and are not required to do so using GNU Wget) then consider combining `https` with [`progress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress). Last need to be installed first, do

```
npm install progress
```

then you might use it like so (adapted from [`progress` - download example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress#download))

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ProgressBar = require('progress');
var https = require('https');
 
var req = https.request({
  host: 'www.example.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/'
}, function (res) {
  var filePath = fs.createWriteStream('index.html');
  res.pipe(filePath);
});
 
req.on('response', function(res){
  var len = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);
 
  console.log();
  var bar = new ProgressBar('  downloading [:bar] :rate/bps :percent :etas', {
    complete: '=',
    incomplete: ' ',
    width: 20,
    total: len
  });
 
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    bar.tick(chunk.length);
  });
 
  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log('\n');
  });
});
 
req.end();
```

Code do download [www.example.com](https://www.example.com) page and save it as `index.html`, note that unlike url for wget you do NOT include protocol (in this case `https`) in host. `443` is default port for https. `/` is path to resource on server (in this case: main page). `Content-Length` header hold information about total file size.

Comment: thanks. it's a good alternative.

and i note that your first sentence so i read `man wget`.

your guess is right. wget considers redirected output is not tty, so progress bar always falls back to "dot" mode.

add option `--progress=bar:force` can solve my problem (note that `:force` is required).